# Sendng in Outlook 2013 fails with permission error

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

I recently started getting the following error message when I tried to send an email from a group distribution list:

> You can't send a message on behalf of this user unless you have permission to do so. Please make sure you're sending on behalf of the correct sender, or request the necessary permission. If the problem continues, please contact your helpdesk.

I have been able to use the group email in the *From:* section for over three months with no issues. As far as I am aware, no changes have been made to our profiles or accounts.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you verified with your IT dept that your user account has the "Send As" permission on the account you are trying to send from?  If your permission was removed for some reason, you won't be able to Send As from the other account.

Comment: Have you contacted your helpdesk?  Have you verfied if you currently have permissions to send messages on behalf of the group user, something might have recently changed, safe bet thats actually the case.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I have now raised a ticket with the IT dept to check the permission in order to determine if the above suggestion may be the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted our IT and then confirmed that I had the correct permissions setup so no issue there. They recommended just removing the "pre saved" address from the "FROM" field and typing it again. This seems to have solved it!